# Add subArray to an array that contains subArrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the array: `[[1,2,3], [1,2,2], [4,3]]`. Then I want to add the array: `[3,3,3]`. The result should be `[[1,2,3], [1,2,2], [4,3], [3,3,3]]`

My code:

```
const arr1 = [[1,2,3], [1,2,2], [4,3]];
const addArr = [3,3,3];

const result = [].concat(arr1 , addArr );
console.log(result);
```

The log is: `[[1,2,3], [1,2,2], [4,3], 3, 3, 3]` Why?

Thanks

Comment: Not pretty but `[].concat(arr1 , [addArr] )` works also

Comment: @charlietfl why not `arr1.concat([addArr])` !

Comment: Note: If you use `push(addArr)`, any changes to `addArr` will change arr1.  So, make sure you use `push(addArr.slice())` to push a copy, not just a reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because [concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) **merge** two or more arrays together.

> merge is different to add or push into.

It does not add an array as a value into other array but merges values together.

Example :

```js
const array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const array2 = ['d', 'e', 'f'];
const array3 = array1.concat(array2);

console.log(array3);
// expected output: Array ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
// Your guess is : Array ["a", "b", "c", ["d", "e", "f"] ]
```

You can solve your issue by using [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

```js
const arr1 = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 2], [4, 3]];
const addArr = [3, 3, 3];

arr1.push(addArr)
console.log(arr1);
```

Or by add values inside an array ( not recommended ) :

```js
const arr1 = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 2], [4, 3]];
const addArr = [3, 3, 3];

const result = arr1.concat([addArr])
console.log(result);
```

Or maybe the **Classic Fashion** :

```js
const arr1 = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 2], [4, 3]];
const addArr = [3, 3, 3];

arr1[arr1.length] = addArr

console.log(arr1);
```

Answer (score 1):

That's the way [Array.prototype.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) works:

```
const a = [1, []];
const b = [3, 4];
const c = a.concat(b);
// [1,  [],  3,  4]
```

No difference with your code.

#### Concat [nested arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat#Concatenating_nested_arrays)

```js
const arr1 = [[1,2,3], [1,2,2], [4,3]];
const addArr = [[3,3,3]];                // Or also, use [3, 3, 3]...
const result = arr1.concat(addArr);      // ...but than ([addArr]) here
console.log(result);
```

#### [Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) Arrays

```js
const arr1 = [[1,2,3], [1,2,2], [4,3]];
const addArr = [[3,3,3]];           // Wrap into additional []
 
const result = [...arr1, ...addArr]; 
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, because elements types of `arr1` are subarrays but elements types of `addArr` are just integers. So just you need to wrap elements of `addArr` on an array like below and it would work.

```js
const arr1 = [[1,2,3], [1,2,2], [4,3]];
const addArr = [[3,3,3]];

const result = [].concat(arr1 , addArr );
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Concat already returns a new array and does not modifies the existing ones.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, well he just asked for the reason he didn't ask for another solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to append an element to the end of the array.

```js
const arr1 = [[1,2,3], [1,2,2], [4,3]];
const addArr = [3,3,3];
arr1.push(addArr);
console.log(arr1);
```

Using [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) results in this behavior because if any argument given to `concat` is an array, it will append the values of that array. According to MDN:

> The concat method creates a new array consisting of the elements in the object on which it is called, followed in order by, for each argument, the elements of that argument (if the argument is an array) or the argument itself (if the argument is not an array). It does not recurse into nested array arguments.

If you do need to use concat, you will need to put the contents of `addArr` inside an array so that `concat` will work properly.

```js
const arr1 = [[1,2,3], [1,2,2], [4,3]];
const addArr = [3,3,3];
const res = [].concat(arr1, [addArr]);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why it is happening:
.concat adds the content of each array to the new array.

whats inside arr1 is [1,2,3], [1,2,2], [4,3]

whats inside addArr is 3,3,3

hence that result.

How to do it:

```
const arr1 = [[1,2,3], [1,2,2], [4,3]];
const addArr = [3,3,3];

const result = [...arr1, addArr];
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding square brackets around the array `addArr` in the concatenation statement works too:

```
const arr1 = [[1,2,3], [1,2,2], [4,3]];
const addArr = [3,3,3];

const result = [].concat(arr1 , [addArr] );
console.log(result); // [[1,2,3], [1,2,2], [4,3], [3,3,3]]
```